# Why does not this transform take advantage of gpu (or does it)?

Tags: html, css, animation

I was looking into Will Boyd and his silky smooth animation talk on css conf.

Now trying to replicate that without any success (or atleast I think).
When using `transform` It's suppose to take advantage of the gpu so in devtools it shoulden't show as render when taking the option "rendering / paint flashing", but it does. Any ideas?

Comparing Will's examples
[bad fish](http://animation-workshop.herokuapp.com/fish-swimming/index.html?approach=bad&count=20)
[good fish](http://animation-workshop.herokuapp.com/fish-swimming/index.html?approach=good&count=20)

My example
the css difference is this, [full code and demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/tfdbloom/pen/VKQQrA/)

```
@keyframes bad-gpu {
    0%, 100% { left: 0px; }
    50% { left: 400px; }
}

@keyframes good-gpu {
    0%, 100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
    50% { transform: translateX(400px); }
}
```

Comment: Is your browser capable of using hardware acceleration with your gpu?

Comment: Yes, MacBook pro "late 13" using Chrome, also Will's example work just fine, does not show paint flashing.

Comment: Go to `chrome://gpu` and check hardware acceleration

Comment: @Oriol all options are avaliable except for the Rasterization "software only", but I read that is Chromium/android only? Also as I mention before, the example that Will has works fine.

Answer (score -2):

CSS animations are not automatically GPU accelerated. They are being executed by the browser's rendering engine. But if we specify an animation with transform or translate3d then browser uses GPU to render the graphics which is more perform-ant.

Comment: Did you read the question or check the examples? I clearly state a examples with and without `transform` that is GPU.